# NFS Issue w/ one mount (stale file handle)

Tags: centos, nfs, nfsv4

I have 5 NFS exports from an NFS server. From the NFS client, I can connect to all except one I keep getting "Stale file handle". The only difference I can see is that the NFS exports are on different hard drives on the NFS server. Any ideas why all exports work except one (the /Backups/Plesk-Backups/ export)?

**NFS Server:**

```
[root@nfs-server ~]# cat /etc/exports
/Backups/Plesk-Backups/                         10.10.10.0/24(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
/home/XenServer_Virtual_Disk_Storage/           10.10.10.0/24(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
/home/XenServer_ISO_Storage/                    10.10.10.0/24(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
/home/XenServer_Virtual_Disk_Storage/           10.10.3.0/24(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
/home/XenServer_ISO_Storage/                    10.10.3.0/24(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)

[root@nfs-server ~]# exportfs -ra

[root@nfs-server ~]# exportfs
/Backups/Plesk-Backups
                10.10.10.0/24
/home/XenServer_Virtual_Disk_Storage
                10.10.10.0/24
/home/XenServer_Virtual_Disk_Storage
                10.10.3.0/24
/home/XenServer_ISO_Storage
                10.10.10.0/24
/home/XenServer_ISO_Storage
                10.10.3.0/24

[root@nfs-server ~]# df -kh
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos00-root   50G  5.1G   45G  11% /
devtmpfs                   1.2G     0  1.2G   0% /dev
tmpfs                      1.2G     0  1.2G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      1.2G  8.6M  1.2G   1% /run
tmpfs                      1.2G     0  1.2G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                 1014M  287M  728M  29% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos00-home  2.7T  2.1T  673G  76% /home
tmpfs                      237M     0  237M   0% /run/user/0
/dev/sdb1                  7.3T 1007G  6.3T  14% /Backups

[root@nfs-server ~]# fdisk -l
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sda: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1B3D1287-AE98-4E6D-BB25-4F5571A867DF


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048         4095      1M  BIOS boot       
 2         4096      2101247      1G  Microsoft basic 
 3      2101248   5860532223    2.7T  Linux LVM       
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sdb: 8001.6 GB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7E3F31FB-5356-45F2-9742-73F5BF3F31B2


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048  15628052479    7.3T  Linux filesyste primary

Disk /dev/mapper/centos00-root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos00-swap: 2684 MB, 2684354560 bytes, 5242880 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos00-home: 2943.1 GB, 2943138922496 bytes, 5748318208 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

**NFS Client:**

```
[root@nfs-client ~]# mkdir /Plesk-Backups

[root@nfs-client ~]# mount -t nfs 10.10.10.54:/Backups/Plesk-Backups /Plesk-Backups/ -vvv
mount.nfs: timeout set for Mon Jan 14 10:28:01 2019
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.1,addr=10.10.10.54,clientaddr=10.10.10.68'

[root@nfs-client ~]# ls -al /Plesk-Backups
ls: cannot access /Plesk-Backups: Stale file handle

[root@nfs-client ~]# lsof |grep /Plesk-Backups
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() nfs4 file system /Plesk-Backups
      Output information may be incomplete.
```